# sql - Insert code with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write an Insert code with condition - insert if not exist. I tried both ways but I got error message -

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE type = 'commentRepl'
>   at line 1

what am i doing wrong?

1:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `alerts` (type, userID, fromID, refID, createDate) VALUES ('commentReply', ".$mainIndex['userID'].", ".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID'].", ".$refID.", ".get_current_linuxTime().")
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM alerts 
                            WHERE type = 'commentReply'
                            AND userID = ".$mainIndex['userID']."
                            AND viewed = 0)
    ");
```

2:

```
mysql_query("
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM alerts 
                            WHERE type = 'commentReply'
                            AND userID = ".$mainIndex['userID']."
                            AND viewed = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO `alerts` (type, userID, fromID, refID, createDate) VALUES ('commentReply', ".$mainIndex['userID'].", ".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID'].", ".$refID.", ".get_current_linuxTime().")
                    END
            ");
```

Comment: Avoid using _deprecated_ mysql functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the where condition into the select statement unless the insert statement is `insert into select from`

The raw mysql statement would look like

```
INSERT INTO `alerts` (type, userID, fromID, refID, createDate) 
 select 'commentReply',1,1, 3, curdate()
 from alerts a1
 where not exists(
   select 1 from alerts a2
   where a2.type = 'commentReply'
   and a2.userID = 1
   and a2.viewed = 0
 )
```

And since you are using it on PHP so you can use some variables as you want something as

```
mysql_query(
 "INSERT INTO `alerts` (type, userID, fromID, refID, createDate) 
 select 'commentReply',".$mainIndex['userID'].",".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID'].", ".$refID.", ".get_current_linuxTime()."
 from alerts a1
 where not exists(
   select 1 from alerts a2
   where a2.type = 'commentReply'
   and a2.userID = ".$mainIndex['userID']."
   and a2.viewed = 0
 )
");
```

Comment: I got this error - #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this. I hope this will give any idea:

```
$exists = "SELECT email, password FROM agent_register WHERE email='$_POST[email]'";
        $exists_result = mysql_query($exists);
        if (mysql_num_rows($exists_result) > 0) {

            $danger_msg = "Error: This email already exists. Please try again.";
        } else {

            if (mysql_num_rows($exists_result) == 0) {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO agent_register(name, company_name, vat_no, status)
                VALUES('$name', '$company_name', '$vat_no', '0')";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
            }
        }
```